# show contents of link

Tags: javascript, c#, facebook

I've been searching the internet to get some information about how i can be able to detect and show what a url is about. 
Facebook has a good example of what i actually want to achieve: 
If you create a update on facebook and paste in a URL, facebook will detect some information about it and show a box with some text and often the right picture. 
for instance, take: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Mens-Monk-Strap-Loafers-Suede-Lined-Metal-Buckle-Slip-Casual-Dress-Shoes-New-/311170422772 . then it shows the image of the shoe and headline.

Ive found other services which does this with image services and youtube, but what i need is about getting information of products most of the time, so often urls from shops. So the user pastes in a url, and i can detect what that link is about.

any ideer how this can be done ? 
Is it backend code, like c# or javascript ?

Hopefully some of you can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tutorials or offsite service recommendations are off topic for stack overflow, additionally this is written very broadly with no sign of research or code you've written.  I suggest narrowing your focus and including code.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook scrapes pages for specific metadata in the back-end and uses it to generate the snippets you see, which can either be served along with the initial page load or brought in via JavaScript (front-end). From there it's a matter of using CSS and JS to style the popup to your liking.

Depending on how inter-related your site is with the content you want to display, this can be an easy task or a difficult one.